# Typing a response object that has complex model

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

Hello I have a array of objects which are 4 different types but they all share:

```js
type EventBase = {
    '@timestamp': string;
    agent: Agent;
    service: Service;
    processor: Processor;
    event: Event;
    labels: Labels;
    observer: Observer;
    ecs: Ecs;
    trace: { id: string };
    timestamp: { us: number };
}
```

And if we go one level deeper we have transactions and spans, in transactions (RequestTransaction, HttpRequestTransaction) and inside spans (HttpSpan, ElasticsearchSpan).

```js
enum TransactionType {
    'request',
    'http-request'
}

type TransactionRoot = {
    client: Client;
    source: Source;
    url: Url;
    user_agent: Useragent;
}

type RequestTransaction = TransactionRoot & {
    cloud: Cloud;
    host: Host;
    http: Http;
    parent: Instance;
    process: Process;
    user: { name: string };
    transaction: Transaction;
}

type HttpRequestTransaction = TransactionRoot;

type Transaction {
    duration: Timestamp;
    name: string;
    id: string;
    page: Page;
    span_count: Spancount;
    type: string;
    sampled: boolean;
}
```

Transactions are distinguishable by transaction.type property (request & http-request). I want to create a type where I can narrow it down further. So for example when I type cloud inside object I want typescript compiler to understand oh this is RequestTransaction and all other properties are necessary.

And lastly I also wanna have conditional to differentiate ElasticsearchSpan from HttpSpan by looking at properties e.g if it has cloud then it must be ElasticsearchSpan.

```js
type SpanRoot = {
    destination: Destination;
    parent: TransactionParent;
    span: Span;
    transaction: TransactionParent;
}

type HttpSpan = SpanRoot & {
    client: Client;
    http: Http;
    'url.original': string;
}

type ElasticsearchSpan = SpanRoot & {
    cloud: Cloud;
}
```

And combine all these as Events because all these are coming from API in same level inside an array. `Events= Either HttpSpan,ElasticsearchSpan,RequestTransaction,HttpRequestTransaction` and I should be able to narrow it down these. I tried a lot of ts magic but none satisfied my needs and super frustrated about this simple thing can feel so advanced while trying to write types. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than unions? `type A = B | C`. It should address what you're describing here.

Comment: unions didn't really help a lot

Comment: Hmm, would you be able to post an example in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). It'd be great to see the code that is trying to narrow down the types. When you say you want a type that can be either `A` or `B`, that's `A | B` and you should be able to narrow it down by check their unique properties.

Comment: As @Amiratak88 also mentioned, unions might fix your problem when using type guards. A reference implementation could look like this: [TS Example](https://tsplay.dev/WkMRDN). Does that help you?